# Unit root: differencing vs. using % change vs. taking ln

Tags: unit-root

Let's say your trying to forecast a country's GDP with an ARMA model. Obviously the original series will contain a unit root (at least most of the time), so which series would you use the model on? Is it best practice to just take the first difference? What about using the % change/returns? I also know natural logarithms come into play sometimes. Would you ever use the ln of the series, the ln of the differenced value, or use ln returns?

Potential approach summary:

- differenced values
- % change
- ln of the original series
- ln of difference values
- ln of % change

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The last two will not work because you cannot take logarithms of negative values (which you will have). You should invert the order of operations: first take the logarithm, then difference (for example).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. But is there a rule of thumb as to which to use first? For example, is there any major difference between using the % change vs. differenced values? And is there even any point in taking differenced ln values if the differenced values are already stationary?

Comment: The common way in macroeconomics is using $\Delta \text{log}(GDP)$ (but $\text{log}(GDP)$ may be needed when modelling cointegrated time series).